# Monitoring Springboot 2.0 Tomcat server Thread utilization

Tags: java, spring-boot, tomcat, monitoring

I have started my springboot application with following tomcat parameters

```
-Dserver.tomcat.max-threads=400
-Dserver.tomcat.max-connections=4000
```

I want to monitor busy thread and busy connection size?

Is there a built-in solution inside springboot? Otherwise Do I need to get mbeans?

Found similar  [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48440800/monitor-tomcats-internal-threadpool-without-using-jmx-in-a-spring-boot-app) but solution is not given yet.

Thanks.

Comment: it should be like that https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43347451/monitor-spring-embedded-tomcat-metrics

Answer (score 20):

At first, I use Spring Boot Actuator and Micrometer. But It does not show tomcat thread utilization. So I configured the application.yml like this.

```
server:
  port: 3200
  address: 0.0.0.0
  tomcat:
    max-threads: 4000
    mbeanregistry:
      enabled: true
```

I set `server.tomcat.mbeanregistry.enabled` to true. Then Tomcat threads utilization is shown in /actuator/metrics.

This is my output.

```
{
  "names": [
    "http.server.requests",
    "http.server.requests.histogram",
    "jvm.buffer.count",
    "jvm.buffer.memory.used",
    "jvm.buffer.total.capacity",
    "jvm.classes.loaded",
    "jvm.classes.unloaded",
    "jvm.gc.live.data.size",
    "jvm.gc.max.data.size",
    "jvm.gc.memory.allocated",
    "jvm.gc.memory.promoted",
    "jvm.gc.pause",
    "jvm.memory.committed",
    "jvm.memory.max",
    "jvm.memory.used",
    "jvm.threads.daemon",
    "jvm.threads.live",
    "jvm.threads.peak",
    "jvm.threads.states",
    "logback.events",
    "process.cpu.usage",
    "process.files.max",
    "process.files.open",
    "process.start.time",
    "process.uptime",
    "system.cpu.count",
    "system.cpu.usage",
    "system.load.average.1m",
    "thread.pool.core.size",
    "thread.pool.max.size",
    "thread.pool.pool.size",
    "thread.pool.thread.count",
    "tomcat.cache.access",
    "tomcat.cache.hit",
    "tomcat.global.error",
    "tomcat.global.received",
    "tomcat.global.request",
    "tomcat.global.request.max",
    "tomcat.global.sent",
    "tomcat.servlet.error",
    "tomcat.servlet.request",
    "tomcat.servlet.request.max",
    "tomcat.sessions.active.current",
    "tomcat.sessions.active.max",
    "tomcat.sessions.alive.max",
    "tomcat.sessions.created",
    "tomcat.sessions.expired",
    "tomcat.sessions.rejected",
    "tomcat.threads.busy",
    "tomcat.threads.config.max",
    "tomcat.threads.current"
  ]
}
```

Comment: Could you share the output parameters you are monitoring

Comment: @AhmetKarakaya I added an output to my answer. Is it what you want to see?

Comment: @Wachira I have enabled this property in my spring boot application.properties. Is there something else to be done? I am still not seeing these metrics in the output.

Answer (score 0):

One easy to do this is by using Spring Actuator with [Micrometer](https://micrometer.io/docs) on top of it. You get instant JMX metrics and you can also declare your own custom ones.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Spring Boot Actuator](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-boot-actuators) (/metrics endpoint) that gives information about memory, heap, processors, threads, classes loaded, classes unloaded, thread pools, etc.

For example, this endpoint returns:

```
"threads.peak" : ...,
"threads.daemon" : ...,
"threads" : ...,
```

Also, you can get a thread dump in case if you need to by using /threaddump endpoint.

Comment: but this gives all threads in applications, but I need to focus on tomcat threads?